# How to get multiple choices in segment dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working on a dashboard with power bi and i have this problem.
I got a segment date before Juin (value = False) and after Juin (value = True) and i have a measure that calculates the cumulative.
I want to create histogram visual with this measurement and show the cumulative throw the fiscal months.

This is my measure :

```
# demandes distinctes =  CALCULATE(
    COUNT(admissions[bk_admis]), 
    USERELATIONSHIP(admissions[DT_RECEPTION], 'date'[Date] ))
```

This is my cumalitive measure :

```
test = TOTALYTD([# demandes distinctes], 'date'[Date],"3/31")
```

I want to test if the month in the segment is before Juin than show only the cumalitive measure with two months Mai and April and after Juin show the months after and if the segment is multiple choice i need to show the initial cumalitive measure.

So this is what i did :

```
test before = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(admissions[bk_admis]), 
    USERELATIONSHIP(admissions[DT_RECEPTION], 'date'[Date]),FILTER('date','date'[Date]<DATE(2023,06,01)))

CUMM before = CALCULATE(TOTALYTD([test before], 'date'[Date],"3/31"),FILTER('date','date'[Date]<DATE(2023,06,01)))

test after = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(admissions[bk_admis]), 
    USERELATIONSHIP(admissions[DT_RECEPTION], 'date'[Date]),FILTER('date','date'[Date]>=DATE(2023,06,01)))

CUMM after= CALCULATE(TOTALYTD([test after], 'date'[Date],"3/31"),FILTER('date','date'[Date]>=DATE(2023,06,01)))
```

and the final cumalitive measure :

```
test total = if( 
SELECTCOLUMNS('date',"bef",'date'[filtre_date_1er_juin_2023])="FALSE",
CUMM before,
if( 
SELECTCOLUMNS('date',"aft",'date'[filtre_date_1er_juin_2023])="TRUE",
CUMM after,
 test
 )
 )
```

If the selected value on the segment is True or False it is working but if all the values are selected nothing works.

Comment: So if date before June 23 (ie `'date'[filtre_date_1er_juin_2023]` is "FALSE"), then use `CUMM before`, if on or after June 23 (ie `'date'[filtre_date_1er_juin_2023]` is "TRUE"), then use `CUMM after`. What if the range is May to July, what do you want it it to do?

Comment: All what you explained is working but the problem is if the segment is select all (True and false are both selected) i need to show the cumalitive of the inital measure ( as i named test) and my dax doesn't consider it

Answer (score 0):

You could try simplifying your conditional to:

```
test total =
  SWITCH( SELECTEDVALUE('date'[filtre_date_1er_juin_2023]),
    "TRUE", [CUMM after],
    "FALSE", [CUMM before],
    [test] 
  )
```

`SELECTEDVALUE` will return `BLANK()` if there is more that one selected value.

Comment: And what about the both segment are selected TRUE and FALSE ???

Comment: The it will use "CUM before", isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: No u can verify my test total i did 2 conditions : if before then cum before else if after then cum after else test (cum total)

Comment: Updated answer above - I mis-read your comment initially.